# LRU Cache without HashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, lru

I need to implement an LRU cache system in Java having all the operations perform in O(1), and all the [example](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/leetcode-lru-cache-java/)s on the net use a HashMap, and we can only use queues, stacks, lists, and arrays. Can someone please explain the theory behind the implementation? I didn't quite get it as well...

Comment: A HashMap is basically an array of lists internally.

Comment: I don't see how you can implement an LRU cache with O(1) access without using a HashMap or other data structure that gives you O(1) access by key. What are the keys you use to locate items in your cache?

Comment: I already implemented a fifo cache an array (of Pages), a an array of integers that holds a key for every index in the array or -1 otherwise, and a queue of keys

Comment: Can I bypass the hashmap use with arrays queues orblists?

Comment: What are the keys, the key structure, and the keys expected range?